# confusion regarding XMPP xep-0065 and xep-0096

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I am currently working on xmppframework, Requirements are to transfer the file between two iPhones. I searched for XEPs and found 0065 and 0096

XEP-0065 says:

> XMPP is designed for sending relatively small chunks of XML between
>   network entities and is not designed for sending binary data. However,
>   sometimes it is desirable to send binary data to another entity that
>   one has discovered on the XMPP network (e.g., to send a file).
>   Therefore it is valuable to have a generic protocol for streaming
>   binary data between any two entities on an XMPP network. **The main
>   application for such a bytestreaming technology is file transfer as
>   specified in SI File Transfer [1] and Jingle File Transfer [2].**
>   However, other applications are possible, which is why it is important
>   to develop a generic protocol rather than one that is specialized for
>   a particular application such as file transfer.

Please see the line in bold, its confusing me if file transfer XEPs are SI File Transfer(0096) and Jingle File Transfer(0234), then what is the purpose of this 0065 XEP? why people on net referring sep-0065 for file transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XEP-0065 is for proxied file transfers: you will need such a proxy in your infrastructure, unless you use a public one.

XEP-0096 is much more complex, I wouldn't recommend that for a start, although I would recommend it if you later extensively use large binary transfers/exchanges, as Jingle is used for VoIP at least.

Comment: thanks a lot  for reply, can u also help regarding utilizing 0065 using xmppframework.

Comment: XEP-0065 is not necessarily proxied; it supports both proxied and direct connections.  Also, it's not meaningful to say that XEP-0096 is "more complex" than XEP-0065, as they serve completely different purposes.  XEP-0065 can be compared to [XEP-0047 (In-Band Bytestreams)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html), and XEP-0096 can be compared to XEP-0234, as noted above.

Answer (score 5):

In XMPP there are different protocols (XEPS) for file transfer. Jingle, Bytestreams, OOB, IBB...

The purpose of XEP-0096 is **stream initiation**. So its build on top of the other file transfer protocols to enable seamless file transfers.

So its used to agree on one of the above file transfer protocols between 2 clients for a transfer, and also for finding a fallback method if this fails for any reason.

Alex

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, can u also help regarding utilizing 0065 using xmppframework.