# How to achieve file sharing through xmpp in ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, file-sharing

I am working on a chat application through xmpp i have done one to one and MultiUser Chat. So please tell me how to do file sharing in XMPP.

Comment: if you plan to write your app in JS check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292181/complete-example-of-strophe-js-file-transfer/35358428#35358428

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confusion regarding XMPP xep-0065 and xep-0096](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542789/confusion-regarding-xmpp-xep-0065-and-xep-0096)

Comment: @beaver i m writing code in Obj C.